# How to send binary data to API with Angular js

Tags: angularjs, api, ionic-framework

I am trying to send image binary to an api.

The api has a mode where you can send a url, if i do that the code works fine. So now i want to send binary image from a html canvas. Here's the docs of the api so you can see the parameter https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis/ocrdocument#request

I get an error alert when I call the getOCR method. which leads me to think that the api call isnt being made correctly. pls help.

Here's what my send function looks like.

```
$scope.getOCR = function(imageData){
    var apikey = 'xxxxxx';
    var requestString = 'https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1?apikey='+ apikey +'&file='+ "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    $http.get(requestString).then(function(resp) {
        alert(angular.fromJson(resp.data).text_block[0]['text']);
        }, function(err) {
            alert('error');      
    })
}
```

And here's what it looks like when i call the method

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

        $scope.getOCR(imageData);

    },
    function(err) {
        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, it looks like you're adding the `data:image/jpeg;base64` prefix twice. Once in the `getPicture(options).then()`, then also when you construct the request URL. Use some browser dev tools to inspect your request and verify that it's what you expect.

Edit:
It also looks like the API may be expecting a POST request with the image data as multipart form data? Not entirely sure, the documentation doesn't seem complete.

Comment: It's completely illogical to expect a GET request parameter to accept something like an image. The documentation doesn't seem complete, but POSTing it seems to be the most sensible way.

Comment: no luck. I've tried using POST and removed the redundant "data:image/jpeg;base64" prefix

Comment: Update your post with the error you're receiving and the request info from your browser's dev tools.

Comment: I cant as the image comes from the phone camera in Ionic framework